# Bootstrap 4 beta column height overlaps with navigation

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap Beta 4 and I found that `nav` overlaps my column div, what I might have done wrong here?

```html
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nav Link</a>
      <div id=navbar class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href=#>Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col border">
        Left panel
      </div>
      <div class="col border">
        Right panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you remove the class `fixed-top` from your `nav` element it will stop the overlap.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
</head>    
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"><!--Removed fixed-top-->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nav Link</a>
      <div id=navbar class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href=#>Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col border">
        Left panel
      </div>
      <div class="col border">
        Right panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Alternatively you could add some css to override the positioning of the `nav` element. (This way you don't have to remove the `fixed-top` class from your `nav`)

```
<style>
   .fixed-top{
       position:relative
   }
</style>
```

Hope this helps :-)